# Persistent client-side web storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We are developing in-house web-based application for viewing data reports while targeting on smartphones and tablets. Our customer asked us for possibility that only certain devices could access the content. Hence we use technologies based on javascript/HTML5 we are no capable of reading unique ID like IMEI or device uuid. My idea consists in making random ID (very simple) and storing (not simple) such an ID on server and device using:

localStorage,
cookies,
html5 file api,
webSQL,
indexedDB
wrapped in http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/
or http://samy.pl/evercookie/

The **problem** is that abovementioned techniques are **not** quite **persistent**. They are vulnerable to cookie and/or cache cleaning.

Can we make such an ID "more" permanent or could You find any other workaround to allow connect only certain devices to the site?

Comment: How do people get that cookie to begin with?

Comment: for security reasons alone i doubt that you will find a cross-browser compatible client-side solution offering _unconditional_ persistence. such a beast would boil down to deny the user control of his machine and would open up a vector to denial of (user agent) service. i think, however, that localstorage and websql (note that the latter has been officially deprecated) come quite close, afaik express  acknowledgement is needed in all mainstream browsers and data deletion is independent of cache control.

Comment: @collapsar i was afraid of this answer. There is no way of permanent storage.

Comment: Any idea how to allow only certain devices?

Comment: WebCrypto had a KeyStorage API, but I think it was deprecated in favor of IndexedDB.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at [Dive into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html), Chapter 7, Local Storage.

Comment: Although it's not ideal `window.location.hash` could be considered persistent data storage though each device would need a custom URI.