# how do I use cordova.js on my website to get a unique device id?

Tags: javascript, cordova, web, mobile-website

I need to get a unique id of the device (mobile, tablet, desktop) from my website. (not an app)

I searched online for a solution and I found that cordova.js provides this feature. I don't know how to use cordova on my project.

How do I set it up? I did add the Cordova.js file but it seems I'm missing some steps. How do I use cordova.js, or is there a better way to identify a device uniquely?

Comment: Cordova works together with some classes inside your mobile app and there is where it takes its info. Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24190436/2149366. It may help you

Comment: I seen that link before but I don't really know how to set it up an am not building an app am building a website using HTML and CSS and php and JavaScript

Comment: Yes. That's why you won't be able to retrieve the uuid since phonegap depends on those java/objective c classes to properly get device info. Also permissions for it are required

Comment: With "permissions" I refer to app permissions corresponding to each platform to access device info.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `cordova.js` approach won't work, since it requires the full framework.

If you just want a unique ID, you could generate a GUID in javascript, and then stick it in a cookie. and have code check if that cookie value exists, and if not, add it.

Comment: This should be able to identify devices uniquely, since each device will set it's own cookie

Comment: Yes create Alan Files how I couldn't think about that the cookies will do the work . thanks a lot for this sir .

Comment: Happy to help! if you liked the answer, please mark it as 'accepted' http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer