# React popup only one time showing according to IP address

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-redux, popup

I made a popup section with "React-js Popup package" and I want to know how could I customize it in order to show it only once time per User IP address. I mean when the same user open my website the pop up will not be shown to him one more time.

Comment: Do you have a backend to save something like that?

Comment: Yes, I have backend

Answer (score 1):

If you have a backend, you can send a request to your server.

This will extract the ip adresse from that call and check, if a call from that ip was already made.

If not, it will return true or something and will save the ip in a database.

If the ip is already saved, just return false.

Wait for the response in your frontend and show the popup, if the response is true.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, we have to track a computer's unique identification, not an IP address.
The IP address can be changed. I think you want to show popup once per computer.

And @Domino987's way is correct.

Check this answer to get the unique.

[Unique device identification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738161/unique-device-identification)

Comment: If he wants the computer, using cookies or localStorage should be suffice to track that IMO.

Comment: @Domino987 we usually use localStorage or cookie to check if the user is the first time for our website. but it is not perfect solution coz users can remove history. He wants only once.